# Bash file not completing correctly

Tags: bash, ufw

I have written the following bash script which is designed to create a file if the UFW rules get changed on a server.  The existence of this file will then be checked with Zabbix.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/tmp/ports.txt"
file_open="/tmp/open_ports.txt"
md5_file=$(md5sum /tmp/ports.txt | awk '{ print $1 }')
md5_file_open=$(md5sum /tmp/open_ports.txt | awk '{ print $1 }')
file_diff="/tmp/ports_diff"

if [[ ! -f $file ]]; then
  touch $file && sudo ufw status|grep ALLOW > $file
fi

if [ -f $file_diff ];then
rm $file_diff
fi

sudo ufw status|grep ALLOW > $file_open

if [ $md5_file != $md5_file_open ];then
touch $file_diff
fi
```

What i'm finding is that sometimes the file doesnt get created or deleted when it should but if I run the command the 2nd or 3rd time without anything further changing, it does.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Is `sudo` for the particular user configured to run without password?

Comment: Yeah, command executes fine manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the first call the files "/tmp/ports.txt" and "/tmp/open_ports.txt" don't exist. After the first run both files should be created and the diff is empty.

Afer this, the `ufw status` changes.

In the next run, the statements

```
md5_file=$(md5sum /tmp/ports.txt | awk '{ print $1 }')
md5_file_open=$(md5sum /tmp/open_ports.txt | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

will process the original files (without the changed status), so they will be operating on the files that are equal. No diff will be found.
During this run `$file_open` will be filled with the new value, but the `md5sum` function is not called after this change. The diff wile will nogt be made.

The next run will start with the changed `$file_open`, and the difference will be found.

When the status is changed back to the original value, the first run the md5 on the old files, claining to see a difference and not deleting the diff file. This run will also write the `$file_open` with the new values, that will be detected the next run.

Solution:
Move the 2 md5sum lines  until after the last `sudo`.